# For two variables of exactly the same type, why do they get different results when they are initialized?

Tags: c++

```
UINT arrReadAddr[20];   memset(arrReadAddr, 0, 20);
UINT arrReadData[20];   memset(arrReadData, 0, 20);
```

[image]

For two variables of exactly the same type, why do they get different results when they are initialized? My idea is definitely that the array elements are all initialized to 0

Comment: Did you consider `memset(arrReadData, 0, 20 * sizeof (UINT));`? You initialize the first 20 bytes only but the arrays have more storage.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat even better: `memset(arrReadData, 0, sizeof arrReadData)` which works even we change the number of elements in arrReadData

Comment: @phuclv This came in my mind as well but I was distracted by the fact that the OPs dump for `arrReadData` shows only four `0`s instead of five I had expected assuming that `sizeof (UINT)` == 4... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing 20 bytes! If, however, `sizeof(UInt) != 1` you aren’t really initializing the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is posted with a C++ tag and not a C tag:

```
std::array<UINT, 20> arrReadAddr;
std::array<UINT, 20> arrReadData;

arrReadAddr.fill(0);    
arrReadData.fill(0);
```

Details are [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Or even simply `std::array<UINT, 20> arrReadAddr{};`.

Answer (score 0):

`memset` takes size in **bytes**

your array is `UINT`. So only quater of it would be zeroed.